# why node chains in algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am reading Data Structures and Algorithms. There I found about Node's and Node chains. Why do we have to use Node chains (I mean why do we really need to store the pointer of next node) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives us a lots of features, I just list few of them :

- It gives you ability to **Insert** every where you want with `O(1)`.

  - just consider we have two node A and B and it is like `A->next = B` I mean it is `A->B`, if you want insert C in the middle of `A` and B you could simply `A->next = C` and `C->next = B` and it will be `A->C->B`.
- It gives you ability to **delete** whatever you want with `O(1)`.

  - in the previous example if you want to delete `C` you could do this `A->next = B` so it will be `A->C`.
- It gives you ability to pass your list with just its head.

  - consider you have a linked list like : `A->B->C-> ....` instead of passing All of the nodes to another function you could just pass `A`.

There are lots of data structure and every one of them have its pros and cons. Also there maybe lots of feature for Next in linked list that I didnt mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can grow the chain dynamically as you go, instead of all up-front like you would in an array. You need to store the pointer of the next node so that you can access it. You cannot access it by index like you would an array.